# Replacing only one front strut?

Tags: toyota, suspension, steering, corolla, replacements

I drive a 2014 Corolla LE and recently had my right front shock strut and stabilizer bar link replaced under warranty. Currently the car has 20300 miles on it.

**Questions:**

Steering-weight seems heavier when turning left than right. Could only replacing one strut cause this, and if so, will it normalize after the new strut breaks in?

Is only replacing one front strut acceptable due to the low mileage(read online that struts should be replaced in pairs)?

Thank you!

Comment: Why was the shock replaced? Something broke or something wore out?

Comment: Alignment service should be completed along with strut replacement(s). Was that also completed?

Comment: The right strut was replaced due to damage. There are no issues related to the left front strut other than it having 20k miles on it compared to the right. Also, I have not been told whether an alignment was done.

Comment: The strut is part of the suspension and affects the alignment when replaced. If they skipped the alignment, it may answer why you are experiencing what you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds to me more like an alignment problem that you need to get checked. To do more diagnosis, I would jack the front of the car up so that both front wheels are just off the ground then turn the steering wheel to see if I could still feel the difference in resistance.  If there is a difference, then there is something wrong, because the struts should rotate either way with equal resistance.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the strut has a fault or has been fitted incorrectly.. Then yes, replacing one strut alone will cause the feelings your experiencing in the cars general performance/balance.

Its best to replace struts/shocks in pairs. A strut with 20k on it will be softer and have less internal resistance than a new one, just because it's been used for that 20k. Even a shock that's done 20k on smooth motorways has still been working hard for a good while.

A shock becomes worn over time, you may not even be able to tell just by doing the bounce test, but real world tests whilst the loads of driving WILL show that shock to be weaker and perform less well.

Comment: When you turn the steering, both struts turn, so why should it be more difficult to rotate a strut one way than it is the other way?

Comment: Easier turning in one direction could be caused by the springs being re-fitted with a slight preload.. Sometimes this can happen when the top cup and nut is tightened twisting the spring slightly.. Or its not sat in its cups correctly.